# Implementing "more detailed question" feature?

Tags: feature-request

The current scenario:

There is already a question - just a dummy example: "Does the 8085 have a 64-bit addition instruction?"

The answer is: "no" (maybe "yes" for other questions)

Now someone is interested in the background and asks: "How to do a 64-bit addition on the 8085?" or "WHY is there no 64-bit addition on the 8085?" or so.

I saw that in such cases the second question is marked as "duplicate" although the aspect of the question is different. In fact the second question asks for more details about the first one in such cases.

One example were the questions: "Is it possible to load a 32-bit-DLL into a 64-bit process?" and "Why is it not possible to load a 32-bit-DLL into a 64-bit-process?" (the second one has been marked as "duplicate").

To avoid this it would be handy if there would be the possibility to mark a question as "asking for a different aspect of another question". In this case everyone could see that the question is not a "duplicate" question but it is asking for a special aspect or more details of this question.

It would be useful if there was the possibility to directly ask counter questions to answers. Example: Question: "Is there a 64-bit addition on 8085?", Answer: "No", Counter questions: "How to add 64-bit numbers anyway?" or "What is the reason for this?"

Thanks for reading

Martin

Comment: This is nothing that can't be fixed by the asker being more specific about what they are asking - when pointing to an existing question (or when the first "this is a duplicate of" comment comes up) it is not too difficult to explain why it _isn't_.

Answer (score 5):

> To avoid this it would be handy if there would be the possibility to mark a question as "asking for a different aspect of another question".

There is. You type,

> I've already seen [link to question here], however the answers there don't suffice to solve my problem because [things that are specific to your needs go here].

It's really that simple. This happens *all the time* - in fact, the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) shown to new users features this advice:

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

...Although whether or not anyone reads it is an open question. Indeed, if your question *is* closed as a duplicate, you'll see this text:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

(The "edit this question to explain how it is different" text isn't shown to 3rd-parties)

Answer (score 3):

Good quality answers are expected to go into more detail, especially to yes/no questions.

In your hypothetical example "Does the 8085 have a 64-bit addition instruction?", a yes/no answer is completely valid, but would likely be downvoted because it is a bad answer (albeit a valid one).  A good answer would respond to the implicit "how"/"why" question already.

That being said, there are other cases that I can see asking for a more detailed answer would be more beneficial.  But Stack Exchange already has it covered for you.  It's called a "bounty", where you offer a portion of your own reputation to draw more attention to a question and hopefully draw better answers.  It is a privilege you can earn once you hit 75 rep.

You can start one on any post you want, as long as it

- Is not closed/on hold, and not deleted
- Doesn't have a bounty on it already
- Is at least 2 days old.

There are even badges to encourage you to offer a bounty on your post and on someone else's post (only the first time you do either though).

To start one, click the "start a bounty" link on a question (which is after the comments but before the answers).  If you don't see the link, the post isn't eligible for a bounty yet so you'll have to wait.

[image]

You select how much of your rep you want to offer as a bounty on an answer (you can select an value in increments of 50 from 50 to 500).

Then select the reason.  For the circumstances you identified here, "Improve Details" would be the best fit, but you can select any other reason. And once you select a reason, you'll be able to add a custom message that you can explain what you are looking for.

[image]

Then just sit back and wait for answers.  Once the bounty expires, you can then award the bounty to a specific answer.

For more info, see [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: How can you split a bounty between multiple posts? I've never seen that as an option before. The FAQ you linked to says it's not possible.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire my bad - I misremembered the feature, editing out.